what is the probability that at least one digit of the selected integer will be 6?
If a positive integer that is less than or equal to 1,000 is to be selected at random, what is
the probability that at least one digit of the selected integer will be 6?
This is the answer, I can't understand the part which choose one digit. Instead of 8 I think it should be 9.
8 + 8×9 + 8×9×9 + 1 = 729
↓     ↓           ↓     ↓
one digit  two digits   three digits  four digits
P(no 6) = 729 / 1000
=> 1 - P(no 6) = 1 - 729 / 1000 = 271 / 1000
I couldn't understand why a single-digit number didn't include 0. Some users mentioned that zero is not considered a positive integer. So, based on this understanding, there is no confusion. Additionally, the suggestion to consider all possible conditions by calculating 999 was very helpful. Thank you, my problem has been solved.

Among one-digit positive integers, 8 of them are not the number 6: $1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9$.

@Milten What about zero?

0 is not a positive integer.  For the others, we do not permit a leading 0

I do not understand why the question was closed for lack of context.  It clearly shows effort and asks a specific question about the difference between the poster's thinking and the proof provided.  I'm voting to reopen.

I agree with Robert. This user has asked many questions recently that suggest they are having a problem with combinatorics. In all of the questions, the answer is known but not understood. That is different from someone who is trying to get their homework solved without any effort.

There's another way to look at the problem.  Allow leading $0$s, as necessary, to get a $3$-digit string.  Then there are $9$ acceptable choices for each position, resulting in $9^3$ strings with no $6$s.
One of those strings is $000$.  Although $0$ is not a positive integer, we will say it corresponds to the positive integer $1000$, which does not contain any $6$s.  Every other $3$-digit string corresponds naturally and in a $1$-$1$ manner to a positive integer less than $1000$.  Thus, the answer is precisely $0.729$.
